# Checking participants of a Twilio Video room before connection

Tags: javascript, next.js, twilio, twilio-video

I have a 1:1 person to person room scenario where I want to make sure that they haven't accidentally connected already before entering.
So Person A can only have 1 instance and person 2 can only have one instance. The most recently opened instance supersedes the previous and disconnects their previous one.
I am using `twilio-video` npm package and Next JS and I have the rooms all working great like this.

```
async function connectToRoom(roomId, userType, tracks) {
  //Create a Access Token to connect to the room
  const credsP1 = await getRoomCredentials(roomId + '-' + userType)
  const room = await Video.connect(credsP1.token, {
    name: roomId,
    audio: { name: 'microphone' },
    video: { name: 'camera' },
    tracks: tracks,
  }).catch((error) => {
    if ('code' in error) {
      // Handle connection error here.
      console.error('Failed to join Room:', error.code, error.message)
    }
  })
}
```

In my `useEffect()` Next JS function how can I check to see if I have already connected? I would be able to use the `userType` keyword to check if I am `PersonA` or `PersonB`

I can't quite get [this code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource) translated to the `twilio-video` I am using

```
  client.video.rooms(roomId)
        .fetch()
        .then(room => console.log("check users and do my stuff here"));
```

Can anyone help get this function working?

Thanks